# MouseMove Events not delivered while dragging from TreeViewer (SWT/Mac 10.6.8)

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have researched for several hours with no luck. I know that I can implement the same functionality with a context menu but I wanted to ask if it is possible.

(This is an eclipse plugin using jface and swt components, eclipse luna, openjdk 7)

This is what I try to accomplish:

In ctabfolder ctf, I have several ctabitems ctis. Each cti has a treeviewer.

I want to allow the user to drag any branch of a treeviewer and drop it in another treeviewer that is in another cti.

I was hoping to determine where the cursor is on the ctf while dragging but no events are delivered after dragging started.

The following bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328396 states that is fixed. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: None of them cover the bug. There is the issue that mouse events are not delivered. There was a workaround in a post from 4 years ago. I thought that enough time has passed. Anyway thanks for you effort

Comment: No. It doesn't. I wanted to find help. That's all. Show me the code that works in the situation described. I am busy. Going in other direction